# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable

Tags: swing, exception, jtable, java

I have a [code](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343795/GUI/java/Check-Box-JTable-header) which when run generates a table in swing form which contains a set of checkboxes which can be selected or unselected

When I click on the Check All tab I am able to select/unselect all the other below check boxes but when i select one of the below checkboxes individually I get this error :

```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable
    at com.tps.charts.CheckBoxHeader.handleClickEvent(JTableHeaderCheckBox.java:152)
    at com.tps.charts.CheckBoxHeader.mouseClicked(JTableHeaderCheckBox.java:168)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source) mousePressed......
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The [code](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343795/GUI/java/Check-Box-JTable-header):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JTableHeaderCheckBox {

    private Object colNames[] = {"", "String", "String"};
    private Object[][] data = {};
    private DefaultTableModel dtm;
    private JTable table;
    private TableColumn tc;

    public void buildGUI() {
        dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames);
        table = new JTable(dtm);
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{false, "Row " + (x + 1) + " Col 2", "Row " + (x + 1) + " Col 3"});
        }
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        tc.setCellEditor(table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
        tc.setCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
        tc.setHeaderRenderer(new CheckBoxHeader(new MyItemListener()));
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(sp);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyItemListener implements ItemListener {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            System.out.println("ItemStateChanged");
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source instanceof AbstractButton == false) {
                return;
            }
            boolean checked = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
            for (int x = 0, y = table.getRowCount(); x < y; x++) {
                table.setValueAt(checked, x, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTableHeaderCheckBox().buildGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CheckBoxHeader extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer, MouseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CheckBoxHeader rendererComponent;
    private int column;
    private boolean mousePressed = false;

    public CheckBoxHeader(ItemListener itemListener) {
        rendererComponent = this;
        rendererComponent.addItemListener(itemListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (table != null) {
            JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
            table.addMouseListener(rendererComponent);
            if (header != null) {
                rendererComponent.setForeground(header.getForeground());
                rendererComponent.setBackground(header.getBackground());
                rendererComponent.setFont(header.getFont());
                header.addMouseListener(rendererComponent);
            }
        }
        setColumn(column);
        rendererComponent.setText("Check All");
        setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
        return rendererComponent;
    }

    protected void setColumn(int column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    protected void handleClickEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        if (mousePressed) {
            mousePressed = false;
            JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader) (e.getSource());
            JTable tableView = header.getTable();
            TableColumnModel columnModel = tableView.getColumnModel();
            int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            column = tableView.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);
            if (viewColumn == this.column && e.getClickCount() == 1 && column != -1) {
                System.out.println(" doClick()......");
                doClick();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(" mouseClicked()......");
        handleClickEvent(e);
        /* problem occurs from this line */
        ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("mousePressed(MouseEvent e).......");
        mousePressed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(" mouseReleased()......");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(" mouseEntered()......");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("mouseExited()......");
    }
}
```

with Exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
javax.swing.JTable cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.JTableHeader
```

Comment: IMO, this [code](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343795/GUI/java/Check-Box-JTable-header) is significantly flawed with respect to model-view indexing and coupling. Try moving a column to see the effect.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137786/how-can-i-put-a-control-in-the-jtableheader-of-a-jtable).

Answer (score 2):

On line 152: `JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader)(e.getSource());` you are assuming the event is on the table header. You need to check event source's class to see if it's on the header or an individual checkbox.

Comment: Trying to check the component by e.getComponent().getName() returns me the component name as null each time.How do I check the component name or type ?

Comment: use `e.getSource().getClass().getName()` or `e.getSource() instanceof JTableHeader`

Comment: yea thanks now I am doing a check on the component name (JTable or JTableHeader) and then performing a seperate mouse press action method based on the component.Now I need to check whther all the cells (checkboxes) are fully selected or not and based on this need to select/unselect the JTableHeader (Check All checkBox).I am stuck up here.  Help appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

You are casting the source of the event to a `JTableHeader`:

```
JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader) (e.getSource());
```

and the source is a `JTable` when you click at a cell. I would have two **different** listeners for the header and the cell selection or you can do a hack by checking `event.getSource() instanceof ...` in your mouse-click-listener.